# Distribution of an upper limit of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\{X_{n,j},n\geqslant1,j\geqslant1\}$ be independent and identically distributed random variables. Denote $S_{n,k}=\sum_{j=1}^kX_{n,j}$. Let $\{Z_n,n\geqslant1\}$ be a sequence of random variables which take values in positive integers and converges almost surely to infinity.

Then can we have $\forall~\epsilon>0$,
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty}(|S_{1,Z_n}|\geqslant\epsilon)\right\}=
\mathbb{P}\left\{\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty}(|S_{n,Z_n}|\geqslant\epsilon)\right\}?$$

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. If you want to get better answers for your questions, it's better to include your thoughts on it, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: A good title helps your question be found by those interested in it. See [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: No assumptions about $Z_n$ being independent from $X_{n,j}$?

Comment: Oh,thank you for your notice. I forgot the assumption that $Z_n$ be independent from $X_{n,j}$ and thank you for your futher thought.